# Envoking a web service method with hyperlink

Tags: services

I have successful connected website with a web service SOAP. The SOAP PHP library is working great.
So far I've used a forms that corresponds with the web service, but now I want to invoke a specific method of the web service by clicking on some link.
For an example, the web service has a method "Logout" and I want to pass the xml string after clicking on user/logout. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_user_logout()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_logout/7):

```
function MYMODULE_user_logout($account) {
  // Make your web service call here.
}
```

That hook will be invoked whenever a user logs out, which includes them clicking on any link to user/logout.

Comment: Yes, I've just found before a minute that function. :) thanks.